# We play with $3$ dice. Which sum of pips on the dice is more probable, $10$ or $13$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

*(Question isn't as long as it looks.)*

> We play with $3$ dice. Which sum of pips on the dice is more
>   probable, $10$ or $13$?

Without doing any calculation, I would say that it is more probable to have $10$ as sum of pips because we only have numbers between $1$ and $6$ and because $10$ is lower than $13$, it might be easier to get it. I don't know if this makes sense but that's the very first thing that came to my mind. To not just make a wild guess, I tried to calculate it.

Did I do it correctly and is there a faster / better way of doing it? :)

---

Here are the combinations to get $10$ as sum ($25$ in total):

$$(1,4,5)$$ $$(1,5,4)$$ $$(1,6,3)$$ $$(2,2,6)$$ $$(2,3,5)$$ $$(2,4,4)$$ $$(2,5,3)$$ $$(2,6,2)$$ $$(3,1,6)$$ $$(3,2,5)$$ $$(3,3,4)$$ $$(3,4,3)$$ $$(3,5,2)$$ $$(3,6,1)$$ $$(4,1,5)$$ $$(4,2,4)$$ $$(4,3,3)$$ $$(4,4,2)$$ $$(4,5,1)$$ $$(5,1,4)$$ $$(5,2,3)$$ $$(5,3,2)$$ $$(6,1,3)$$ $$(6,2,2)$$ $$(6,3,1)$$

Combinations for sum $13$ (in total $21$):

$$(1,6,6)$$ $$(2,5,6)$$ $$(2,6,5)$$ $$(3,4,6)$$ $$(3,5,5)$$ $$(3,6,4)$$ $$(4,3,6)$$ $$(4,4,5)$$ $$(4,5,4)$$ $$(4,6,3)$$ $$(5,2,6)$$ $$(5,3,5)$$ $$(5,4,4)$$ $$(5,5,3)$$ $$(5,6,2)$$ $$(6,1,6)$$ $$(6,2,5)$$ $$(6,3,4)$$ $$(6,4,3)$$ $$(6,5,2)$$ $$(6,6,1)$$

---

So for sum $10$ we have probability of $p=\frac{25}{6^3} \approx 11.6$ %

For sum $13$ we have probability of $p=\frac{21}{6^3} \approx 9.72$ %

Thus, it is indeed more probable to get sum $10$.

Comment: Just looking at your list quickly where is $(1,3,6)$? $(5,4,1)$?  It's hard to enumerate carefully.  I'd use generating functions, expand $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3$.

Comment: Informally:  the expected roll of one die is $3.5$ so your expectation here is $3\times 3.5=10.5$.  Rolls nearer the average are more probable than those far from the average.

Comment: Die is singular; dice is plural; dices (third person singular) means to cut into small cubes.

Comment: If you are not familiar with generating functions, another approach to counting the favorable cases is to find the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10$ in the positive integers subject to the restrictions that $x_k \leq 6$ for $1 \leq k \leq 3$ and $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 13$ in the positive integers subject to the same restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more likely to get 10 than 13, although your reasoning is incorrect: would you say that 3 is the most likely outcome then?

For this particular use case: every die, on average, gives a value of $\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6} = 3.5$. So on average, 3 dice give a sum of 10.5, which is closer to 10 than 13.

Note that it's quite specific to this use case: if you had to compare, say, 10 and 11, you'd probably need to look more closely. Also, this method wouldn't work for bimodal distributions, e.g. if the dice were more likely to be a 1 or 6 than a 3 or 4.

Answer (score 2):

By the stars-and-bars formula, if $n,r$ are positive integers, the equation
$$x_1 + \cdots + x_n = r$$
has exactly ${\large{\binom{r-1}{n-1}}}$ solutions in positive integers $x_1,...,x_n$.

Let the values of the dice rolls be represented as an ordered triple $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$.

First count the number of triples $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ for the case $d_1+d_2+d_3=10$ .  . .

If we temporarily ignore the condition $d_1,d_2,d_3 \le 6$, the stars-and-bars formula for the equation
$$d_1+d_2+d_3=10$$
would yield ${\large{\binom{10-1}{3-1}}} = {\large{\binom{9}{2}}}$ positive integer triples $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$.

We need to subtract the count of the triples where at least one of $d_1,d_2,d_3$ exceeds $6$.

Given that $d_1+d_2+d_3=10$, at most one of $d_1,d_2,d_3$ exceeds $6$.

Consider the case $d_3 > 6$.

The number of positive integer triples $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ such that $$d_1+d_2+d_3=10\;\;\text{and}\;\;d_3 > 6$$ 
is the same as the number of positive integer pairs $(d_1,d_2)$  such that $$d_1+d_2<4$$
which is the same, using $x_3$ as a dummy variable, as the number of positive integer triples $(d_1,d_2,x_3)$ such that 
$$d_1+d_2+x_3=4$$
which, by the stars-and-bars formula, has ${\large{\binom{4-1}{3-1}}} = {\large{\binom{3}{2}}}$ solutions.

Hence the corrected count is
$${\small{\binom{9}{2}}} - {\small{\binom{3}{1}}}{\small{\binom{3}{2}}} = 27$$
where the factor ${\large{\binom{3}{1}}}$ accounts for the choice of which of $d_1,d_2,d_3$ exceeds $6$.

By analogous reasoning, the number of triples $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ for the case $d_1+d_2+d_3=13$ is
$${\small{\binom{12}{2}}} - {\small{\binom{3}{1}}}{\small{\binom{6}{2}}} = 21$$

Comment: Everything looks good except that $\binom{9}{2} - \binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2} = 27$.

Comment: Oops. Will fix it. Thanks.